# Class Controller not found while loading

Tags: symfony, controller, wamp

I was working on my first project with Symfony, I created my first controller. And this error appears.

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RviPr.png)

I tried to

> composer update

and I got the same problem! 
[The problem that appear when i update the composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPXjm.png)

here is the code of TestController.php

```
  <?php 
    namespace App\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

    class TestController extends Controller {
        /**
        * @Route("/")
        * @Method ({"GET"})
        */
        public function index() 
        {
           //return new Response('<html><body>Hello world</body></html>');    
            return $this->render('articles/index.html.twig');
        }

    }
```

index.html.twig file has only a `<h1> test </h1>` on it

What makes that problem appear? and how to fix it without deleting the project and creating it again!
thanks

Comment: Please don't use images in questions.  Just copy/paste the relevant lines and put them in a code block.  And the answer below is correct.  Consider acknowledging it.

Comment: Okay, I got it :)

Comment: Someone here is going through the same tutorial as me, hahah

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` has been [deprecated since v4.2.0](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#420) and [removed since v5.0.0](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500), use `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController` instead.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TestController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index() 
    {
       //return new Response('<html><body>Hello world</body></html>');    
        return $this->render('articles/index.html.twig');
    }

}
```